# How can i get a Id parameter from URL in vb.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor

I'm writing code to perform CRUD operations using JavaScript and VB.NET MVC. I'll require a method to send parameters from Controller to the View, but I don't know how to catch the value from the URL.

Following is my controller:

```
' GET: Bodega/Index/5
    Function Edit(ByVal id As Integer, ByVal collection As FormCollection) As ActionResult
        Try
            Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("conexion").ConnectionString
            Using con As New SqlConnection(constr)
                Using cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM bodega WHERE id = @Id")
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", id)
                    cmd.Connection = con
                    Dim data As New List(Of Bodega)()
                    con.Open()
                    Using sdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                        While sdr.Read()
                            data.Add(New Bodega() With {
                            .id = Convert.ToInt32(sdr("id")),
                            .nombre = sdr("nombre").ToString(),
                            .ubicacion = sdr("ubicacion").ToString(),
                            .lugar = sdr("lugar").ToString(),
                            .lat = sdr("lat").ToString(),
                            .lng = sdr("lng").ToString()
                        })
                        End While
                    End Using
                    con.Close()
                    Return View("Index", id)
                End Using
            End Using
        Catch e As Exception
            Return RedirectToAction("Index")
        End Try
    End Function
```

I'm sending the id to the View via the `return` statement, but in the view i don't know what command can use.

The URL format is:

> localhost/Bodega/Edit/5

I need catch the ID 5. If as possible save into a hidden input or send to a javascript code to load the data pre-load for the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

In the Edit view that is calling the Edit action, make sure that the route value is called id so that it can bind to the id parameter. Also, it doesn’t seem like you’re using the FormCollection parameter. And did you mean to pass the new Bodega instance you’re creating over to the view instead of the id? I’m guessing that you are looking up a bodega to be edited in an edit view?